# Reminder application

Tags: android

I am developing a reminder application. I am generating notifications using notification manager class, when the timeline crosses.But if my cell phone is switched off ,I am unable to see these notifications. Not even when i switch it on again.

Even if i switch it off and switch on again, i think the pending intents are destroyed and no notification is generated.

How do i get it when the phone is switched on again ?

Comment: Do you mean switched off, as in cut the power? Your program won't be running if the phone is completely switched off. Not even the built in alarm-clock works then.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the `AlarmManager`:

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html:

> This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future. When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered for it is broadcast by the system, automatically starting the target application if it is not already running. **Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time)**, but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted.